# 3.5 Inch SPI TFT LCD Display goes black for Android Things

Tags: android, raspberry-pi, spi, touchscreen, android-things

I have a KeDei 3.5 ich SPI TFT LCD Display. I attached to Raspberry Pi with Android Things Image. When I boot the RPi, nothing is shown, only displays a black screen. The display is getting powered up, and I can differentiate between it's on and off state. But when I try remote display (followed steps from [this post](https://medium.com/@abhi007tyagi/android-things-remote-screen-access-aff870c29682)), I can see the display properly.
Logcat output which I think is related to display:

```
mBaseDisplayInfo=DisplayInfo{"Built-in Screen", uniqueId "local:0", app 640 x 480, real 640 x 480, largest app 640 x 480, smallest app 640 x 480,mode 1, defaultMode 1, modes [{id=1, width=640, height=480,fps=60.000004}], colorMode 0, supportedColorModes [0], hdrCapabilities android.view.Display$HdrCapabilities@1d6308, rotation 0, density 240 (0.0 x 0.0) dpi, layerStack 0, appVsyncOff 1000000, presDeadline 16666666, type BUILT_IN, state ON, FLAG_SECURE, FLAG_SUPPORTS_PROTECTED_BUFFERS, removeMode 0}
```

I tried latest Raspbian Image and dev preview 0.4.1 as mentioned [here](https://medium.com/@dirkvranckaert/android-things-and-a-kedei-3-5-display-9587858121b6). Tried with HDMI config given in the same link. Nothing works except the rpi_35_v6.3_ubuntu_mate_15_kedei image from [KeDei vendor](http://kedei.net/raspberry/raspberry.html).

Display Specs:

- 480x320 16bit/18bit
- version 6.3 2016/11/1

Android Things:

- OS: 0.6.1-devpreview
- Build: OIM1.171126.016
- Empty Bundle

Comment: I've got the same display model - did you manage to make it work with raspbian using  any drivers?

Comment: I tried with Ubuntu Mate provided by KeDei and it works. You can check http://kedei.net/raspberry/raspberry.html for raspbian and kali IMGs. Those should work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According [Hardware Platforms](https://developer.android.com/things/hardware/developer-kits.html#hardware_platforms) description, Raspberry Pi with Android Things support Display only via HDMI or DSI interfaces, not via SPI, and there is no built in drivers for it - your KeDei 3.5 ich SPI TFTLCD Display will not work. You can use that display only from your application via SPI commands (something like custom driver), but not from Android Things system.